# Spectral entropy and moments and non stationary signal processing

Tags: signal-analysis

What is Spectral entropy and spectral moments? I know what the normal entropy of a signal is! And also what are some good time-frequency features for the analysis of non-stationary signals?

Comment: the answer given before wasn’t actual differential entropy, but entropy by analogy.